# How to create tags in TextView when receving the data from the server?

Tags: java, android, xml, tags

I have implemented the tags in my android application and sent to the server but the problem arises when receiving the data from the server which contains the tags and I am using the append method on the `EditText` to get the tags. But the problem is that is appends all the data from the server and creates a single tag.

I want to display each tags from the server as an individual tags in the `EditText` box.

Here is my code to get the tags from the server and appending it onto the edittext:

```
for (int i=0; i< Config.vendortag.size(); i++)
{
    mTagsEditText.append(Config.vendortag.get(i) + "\n" + "");
}
```

Comment: Could you please share, how it looks? and xml code for your editText

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with third party library you can check [this](https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete) out. Creating your own taggedTextView will require you to `extend` `TextView` and wrap every token inside a `drawable` something like this.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/transparent"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#AAAAAA" />
    <corners
        android:radius="100dp" />
    <padding
        android:left="5dp"
        android:top="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:bottom="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score -1):

use this library https://github.com/mabbas007/TagsEditText/blob/master/TagsEditText/src/main/java/mabbas007/tagsedittext/TagsEditText.java and use this method to set tags data from server

```
editText.setTags(server data);
```